# MVVM - binding to check box if checkbox checked

Tags: data-binding, mvvm

I want to bind a string value to a text box but only if a check box is checked. So, if the checkbox is checked I want the textbox to display Message 1, if not then display Message 2.

What is the best way to do this? Is it better to use a List property in my object and then depending on if the check box is checked or not depends on which item from within my List<> is displayed

or

is it better to just update the object's property (this time of type string) after the checkbox is selected and then re-bind?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is one MVVM type of approach that assumes you understand INotifyPropertyChanged (you need to!). Play with it and feel free to ask about anything you get stuck on.

## VM (viewmodel code)

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    const string Msg1 = "blah 1";
    const string Msg2 = "blah 2";

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected{
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set {
            if(_isSelected == value) return;

            _isSelected = value;
            MyBoundMessage = _isSelected ? Msg1 : Msg2;

            NotifyPropertyChanged(()=> IsSelected);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(()=> MyBoundMessage);
        }
    }

    public string MyBoundMessage {get;set;}
}
```

V (view XAML)

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyBoundMessage}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great. Sorry for delay in my reply.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that checkbox doesn't have property "IsSelected", you should set property "IsChecked". Also, make sure to enclose property value is quotes.

Comment: OrahSoft, you need to learn about DataBinding - the name of the object is not releavnt

Comment: Should the `if(_isSelected = value)` be `if(_isSelected == value)`? I assume it should be a comparison not an assignment?

Comment: if this was for a checkbox in a datagrid of checkboxes, doesn't binding to `INotifyPropertyChanged` produce something that couldn't get GarbageCollected since you never unhook it? if not, where would be a good place to iterate through the collection for unhooking?