# Setting IsChecked property to true/false doesn't fire checked/unchecked events in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code. No checked/ unchecked event is fired when PlayVideoState value is set to true/false. Does anything missing? please suggest.

```
<CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource PlayButton}" Margin="6" Name="PlayButton" IsChecked="{Binding _Extensions.PlayVideoState, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <ei1:GoToStateAction StateName="VideoOn"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                            <ei1:GoToStateAction StateName="VideoOff"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamily1}" Foreground="{DynamicResource Text01}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="21.333"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Video"/></TextBlock>
                </CheckBox>
```

Comment: Elaborate a little. Do they fire when you check/uncheck with the mouse?

Comment: Google is a wonderful thing.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064888/mvvm-binding-to-check-box-if-checkbox-checked

Comment: You're over-complicating it for yourself.

Comment: Yes, it fires event when i check/uncheck with the mouse. Doesn't fire when PlayVideoState is set to true/fals.

Comment: It isn't supposed to. Fire the event by yourself.